# How to do tensor product between non-rectangular tensors?

Tags: tensors

For example, if I have a non-rectangular tensor

```
t = Table[2, {l, 0, 1}, {m, -l, l}]
```

To tensor product 't' with itself will fail, because 't' is not a rectangluar tensor, i.e., the following code doesn't work

```
TensorProduct[t,t]
```

The result I want to get can be obtained by

```
Table[t[[l1,m1]]*t[[l2,m2]], {l1, 0, 1}, {m1, -l1, l1}, {l2, 0, 1}, {m2, -l2, l2}]
```

This is quite inconvenient, so I want to ask if there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you're seeking for

`Outer[Times,t,t]`